# Can you use a QUERY in Google Sheets using OR logic and the =today() formula for a dynamic date in the past?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to use the `QUERY` function paired with `OR` logic and the `=today()` formula to create a new table from my data set.

The data is on the "DATA" tab and 'QUERY' is on the "QUERY" tab. [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MdQuz6_dSt536f5f1fE2RpF-qtwhQzYzrUFucTDKYRI/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is a horrible recreation of my data table input (I can't figure out how to make an inline table with more than two columns...):

| Column A (ID) | Column B (Date) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/11/2020 |
| 2 | 1/17/2024 |
| 3 | 11/30/2022 |
| 4 | 11/20/2023 |

| Column C (Score1) | Column D (Score2) |
| --- | --- |
| 52 | 60 |
| 44 | 40 |
| 50 | 50 |
| 53 | 60 |

| Column E (Score3) |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 50 |
| 30 |
| 50 |

For my QUERY output table, I am only getting ID rows 2 and 3, but I was expecting to get ID row 1 as well.

Here is a screenshot of my data table input:

[image: Data table input]

Here is a screenshot of my QUERY table output:

[image: Data table output]

Here are my Criteria: Score1 >45, OR Score2 >50, OR Score3 > 50, OR Date 18+ Months ago (As of writing this, anything before July 26, 2022 would meet the criteria, but I would like this to be a dynamic date and update on its own to include 18 months from today's date).

I am looking to make a table containing every row that meets at least one of these 4 criteria with no duplicate rows.

Here is my QUERY formula:

```
=QUERY(DATA!A1:E10, "select A, C, D, E, B where(C < 45 OR D < 50 OR E < 50 OR B > '=today()-548')",1)
```

The part of the 'QUERY' that isn't working is the `OR B > '=today()-548'` portion. I am trying to include rows that have a date greater than 18 months ago (548 days) from today's date. I thought this would be the best way since the data in the columns I am looking to include are not mutually exclusive. The first three criteria are showing up in my list `'C < 45 OR D < 50 OR E < 50'` but the rows that only meet `OR B > '=today()-548'` is not showing up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I would be happy to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=QUERY(DATA!A1:E10, "select A, C, D, E, B where (C<45 OR D<50 OR E<50 OR B<date'"&text(today()-548,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"')")
```

***OR***

```js
=filter({A:A,C:E,B:B},(C:C<45)+(D:D<50)+(E:E<50)+(B:B<today()-548))
```

[image]

Comment: I used your first suggestion, thanks so much! It was really driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```cpp
=QUERY(A1:E10, "select A, C, D, E, B where C < 45 OR D < 50 OR E < 50 OR B < date"&TEXT(EDATE(TODAY(),-18),"'yyyy-mm-dd'"),1)
```

Comment: This also worked, thanks so much for providing this different perspective on the date query!